# Can't get kernel module `uinput` started

Tags: 12.04, kernel, bluetooth, ps3

I'm trying to get my BD remote to work with my Ubuntu media server and XBMC. I've followed the directions here: http://forums.boxee.tv/showthread.php?t=15200

I get everything installed, but `uinput` just never runs. `lsmod | grep uinput` shows nothing, `sudo modprobe uinput` doesn't help.

Because of this, I assume, when I go to the bluetooth manager, I can't pair the remote and the dongle on my server.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you made changes as in the link, you might reboot just to be sure everything loads correctly.

Comment: @belacqua, tried that too. Still no dice.